# Why can I pull from a bare repo on dropbox?

Tags: git, dropbox

This is a newb question from a non-programmer:

Let's say I set up Git and Dropbox together (as in http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/04/using-git-with-dropbox.html) by having a local repo (in my work computer) + a bare repo in Dropbox. Supposedly I can then pull from the bare repo into other Dropbox-linked computers (e.g. my home computer).

In my understanding, a bare repo is one that does not include the actual files but only the .git files. If so, how is it possible that I can pull ALL the files (not just the .git) from the Dropbox bare repo into a local repo on my home computer? These actual files are not on the cloud, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what a "bare repo" contains. It's true that it does not contain *working copy* files, meaning uncompressed copies of the files in your repository. However, the repository itself contains compressed copies of all files (and all historical files) in your repository. When you clone a bare repository, Git by default creates working files that are uncompressed (and a `.git` directory to store the local repository in).